# How to set up rules to email a pdf after creating it with fillPDF

Tags: 7, rules, emails

I am using fillPDF and would like to set up a rule so that once the pdf is created it will create an email, attach the PDF and mail it to a designated recipient. I have looked on line on how to do this but the instructions are very vague saying it is possible and here is a list of modules you will need and no other instructions ([link to instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1642270)). I have tried putting together a rule but it is not working. I was wondering if anyone has accomplished this and what the steps are.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any module to create the pdf or doing it in a custom module you build?

Comment: I am using the [fillPDF module](http://drupal.org/project/fillpdf).